# Olimex Micro A20 Certain GPIO wont function on 18.0.06 but they worked on 17.0.1

Tags: gpio, openwrt, device-tree

I am using a **Allwinner A20 SoC based Olimex Micro A20** as a development board with **openwrt 18.0.6**. I face a strange issue that some of GPIO works perfectly others will accept the commands to set as out put and set value High or Low but physically the output will not change. I have a previous built image based on **LEDE17.0.1** and in that all these GPIOs work fine.

when I issue `cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio`

This is the result

```
gpiochip0: GPIOs 0-287, parent: platform/1c20800.pinctrl, 1c20800.pinctrl:
 gpio-35  (                    |sysfs               ) in  lo
 gpio-36  (                    |sysfs               ) in  lo
 gpio-40  (                    |ahci-5v             ) out lo
 gpio-41  (                    |usb0-vbus           ) out hi
 gpio-80  (                    |sysfs               ) out lo
 gpio-81  (                    |sysfs               ) out lo
 gpio-82  (                    |sysfs               ) out lo
 gpio-87  (                    |sysfs               ) out lo
 gpio-96  (                    |sysfs               ) in  hi
 gpio-97  (                    |sysfs               ) in  hi
 gpio-98  (                    |sysfs               ) in  hi
 gpio-99  (                    |sysfs               ) in  hi
 gpio-100 (                    |sysfs               ) in  hi
 gpio-101 (                    |sysfs               ) in  hi
 gpio-102 (                    |sysfs               ) in  hi
 gpio-103 (                    |sysfs               ) in  hi
 gpio-104 (                    |sysfs               ) in  hi
 gpio-105 (                    |sysfs               ) in  hi
 gpio-106 (                    |sysfs               ) in  hi
 gpio-107 (                    |sysfs               ) in  hi
 gpio-108 (                    |sysfs               ) in  hi
 gpio-109 (                    |sysfs               ) in  hi
 gpio-110 (                    |sysfs               ) in  hi
 gpio-111 (                    |sysfs               ) in  hi
 gpio-113 (                    |sysfs               ) out hi
 gpio-114 (                    |sysfs               ) out lo
 gpio-115 (                    |sysfs               ) out hi
 gpio-117 (                    |sysfs               ) out lo
 gpio-128 (                    |sysfs               ) out lo
 gpio-129 (                    |sysfs               ) out hi
 gpio-130 (                    |sysfs               ) out lo
 gpio-132 (                    |sysfs               ) out lo
 gpio-133 (                    |sysfs               ) out lo
 gpio-134 (                    |sysfs               ) out lo
 gpio-135 (                    |sysfs               ) out lo
 gpio-136 (                    |sysfs               ) out lo
 gpio-137 (                    |sysfs               ) out lo
 gpio-138 (                    |sysfs               ) out lo
 gpio-139 (                    |sysfs               ) out lo
 gpio-202 (                    |sysfs               ) in  hi
 gpio-203 (                    |sysfs               ) in  hi
 gpio-225 (                    |cd                  ) in  lo IRQ
 gpio-226 (                    |a20-olinuxino-micro:) out lo
 gpio-227 (                    |usb2-vbus           ) out hi
 gpio-230 (                    |usb1-vbus           ) out hi
 gpio-231 (                    |sysfs               ) out lo
 gpio-235 (                    |cd                  ) in  hi IRQ
 gpio-256 (                    |sysfs               ) out hi
 gpio-257 (                    |sysfs               ) out lo
 gpio-258 (                    |sysfs               ) out hi
 gpio-259 (                    |sysfs               ) out hi
 gpio-266 (                    |sysfs               ) out lo
 gpio-267 (                    |sysfs               ) out lo
 gpio-270 (                    |sysfs               ) out hi
 gpio-271 (                    |sysfs               ) out hi
 gpio-273 (                    |sysfs               ) out hi
 gpio-275 (                    |sysfs               ) out hi
```

In this case gpio257 for example would work properly while gpio138 will accept all the commands but physically the output will be same

```
ls /sys/class/gpio/
export        gpio109/      gpio128/      gpio139/      gpio270/      gpio96/
gpio100/      gpio110/      gpio129/      gpio202/      gpio271/      gpio97/
gpio101/      gpio111/      gpio130/      gpio203/      gpio273/      gpio98/
gpio102/      gpio113/      gpio132/      gpio231/      gpio275/      gpio99/
gpio103/      gpio114/      gpio133/      gpio256/      gpio35/       gpiochip0/
gpio104/      gpio115/      gpio134/      gpio257/      gpio36/       gpiochip413/       
gpio105/      gpio116/      gpio135/      gpio258/      gpio80/       unexport
gpio106/      gpio117/      gpio136/      gpio259/      gpio81/
gpio107/      gpio118/      gpio137/      gpio266/      gpio82/
gpio108/      gpio119/      gpio138/      gpio267/      gpio87/
```

How can I solve this issue .

There are several such GPIO at least 8 -9 that I have encountered

I see that all the pins that have **130 -139 numbers wont work . Those with 250+ will work**

The following are the pins I am interested in and all the pins in 200 series work as expected. The ones in 130-139 range wont work in the new image but they were working in previous image

```
/bin/echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio257/value
/bin/echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio258/value
/bin/echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio259/value
/bin/echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio271/value
/bin/echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio270/value
/bin/echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio256/value
/bin/echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio138/value
/bin/echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio139/value
/bin/echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio135/value
/bin/echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio137/value
/bin/echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio134/value
/bin/echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio136/value
/bin/echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio133/value
/bin/echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio266/value
/bin/echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio267/value
/bin/echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio132/value
```